# Why directly using class selector of <li> not work?

Tags: html, css

my partial html codes :

```js
<body>
        <div id="div1" class="calendar">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><h2>1</h2><p>one</p></li>
                <li><h2>2</h2><p>two</p></li>
                <li><h2>3</h2><p>three</p></li>
                <li><h2>4</h2><p>four</p></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="text">
                <h2>arrangement</h2>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

and my css codes:

```css
<style>
body{background:skyblue;}
#div1 {height:700px;width:440px;background:gray;margin-left:400px;margin-top:10px;position:absolute;}
#div1 ul{margin-top:20px;}
.text{background:white;height:150px;width:335px;font-size:15px;margin-top:520px;margin-left:50px;position:relative;border:2px solid blue;padding-left:10px;}
#div1 ul li{list-style:none;height:100px;width:100px;background:black;float:left;margin:10px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;color:white;}
.active{background:white;color:red;}
</style>
```

I find that only when I use `#div1 .active{...}` can it work. I want to know the reason why `.text{...}`can work ,but  `.active{...}` can not work.

I run codes on Chrome.

Comment: You're trying to overwrite the background, you could use !important for this: https://jsfiddle.net/anmcosx4/

Comment: Or use the :not selector for background and color: https://jsfiddle.net/rb6njpyf/

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit?

Comment: I want to let the first <li> in<ul> be different with others.And the question is solved.I won't overwrite the background. @Kevin

Comment: @kirini , Yeah! seems it is solved. But you could use `li:first-child` also.